# Using the C++11 ABI on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7

Tags: c++, redhat, rhel7

I use devtoolset-11 to get gcc 11 on Red Hat EL7. I just learned that this configuration does not support the C++11 ABI (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1546704). I'm trying to figure out options. From the ticket it's not clear to me what made it difficult to support. Can I just compile gcc from scratch to reenable this feature? If so, do I need to ship libstdc++.so or other binaries? What can of worms might I be opening up?

Comment: The bug you link to seems to be specific to devtoolset-7, no?

Comment: I don't think so - I didn't interpret it that way. But I confirmed this was the case via code anyhow.